# SSL connection using pgjdbc-ng as Java driver for Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, pg-jdbc

I'm facing a great problem in connecting to a Postgres database using https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng/. I need this lib because I need to get asynchronous notification from the database.

I'm trying to connect to a remote database using SSL an I'm doing this:

```
Class.forName("com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver");

String url = "jdbc:pgsql://host:5432/db"
                        + "?ssl.mode=Require";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "pwd");
```

But, when I try to do that I get an `IllegalStateException`. This is the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:189)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver.connect(PGDriver.java:77)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver.connect(PGDriver.java:52)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
 at it.polito.mobile.testpostgres.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
 at it.polito.mobile.testpostgres.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:35)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ProtocolFactoryImpl.translateConnectionException(ProtocolFactoryImpl.java:285)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ProtocolFactoryImpl.connect(ProtocolFactoryImpl.java:199)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ProtocolFactoryImpl.connect(ProtocolFactoryImpl.java:90)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.<init>(BasicContext.java:130)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGConnectionImpl.<init>(PGConnectionImpl.java:185)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:180)
 ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$LazyChannelPromise.executor(SslHandler.java:1491)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:388)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:283)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.syncUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:225)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.syncUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:32)
 at com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ProtocolFactoryImpl.connect(ProtocolFactoryImpl.java:132)
 ... 15 more
```

Before, I was using the standard library `org.postgresql.Driver` and everything worked fine...

Does anybody know how to help me?

Thank you so much!
Marco

Comment: This looks like a bug in the driver. That said, `ssl.mode=Require` is potentially insecure (it doesn't verify the cert), what you'd want is `ssl.mode=VerifyFull`.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same issue - ever find a fix?

Comment: It's a bug...as far as I know it was a netty (a lib used in this lib) issue and it has been solved in netty but the dependency has to be updated, so once the library for the postgres driver will be updated pointing to the new netty  version, this issue should be solved...